# Having trouble changing voice channel's name in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot who has two scripts to be run in parallel to each other. One is for the major work, and this one is just for changing the name of a specific voice channel when a condition is fulfilled. For the time being, I am running it in a while loop as:

```
from datetime import datetime
import discord
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
    while True:
        await client.get_channel(805833860457824267).edit(name=datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
        print('ok')
        time.sleep(3)

client.run(<token>)
```

When I run this script, I get no error and also the name gets edited twice before it just stops doing it. If I rerun it, after the first time, no such changes are reflected in the channel's name. So, for testing I have to delete the channel and create another one like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i wanted to Mention that you should put a Delay of 6 Minutes before Changing a channels name again. And if im here i can give u a answer.
You could use

```
channel = bot.get_channel(your channels id must be a int)
await channel.edit(name="your name")
```

This code should do it.

Comment: I hope i could help you.

Comment: It's the ratelimit for editing channels 2 requests per 10 minutes, not quite 6 minutes, more about 5

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Is that restriction imposed per client or per script?

Comment: Its a rate limit per channel